# iOS-6 UI Issues and Orientation Support

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, ios6

I have tested my application(iPhone and iPad) on iOS 5.1, till here it was working fine. But now when I downloaded iOS 6.0 SDK Beta and tested my apps on the Simulator, UI of the application is getting worst. Orientation is also not working fine with the iPad App.

**Note - Maybe it is because of UIKit changes Apple has made in iOS 6. But then the question is how do we make it compatible with the latest iOS? Do I need to make some changes in Code? 
Searched at some places but didn't get any exact solution to this problem.**

Thanks
Ak

Comment: Ask this question on the apple developer forums instead.

Comment: Can’t really answer this without seeing all your code and Interface Builder files. Anyway, as it’s still in beta and under NDA, you shouldn’t be asking this here at all. Try working out specific test cases that are causing trouble, and if you get stuck ask on the Apple DevForums instead.
http://devforums.apple.com

Comment: iOS 6 is still under NDA: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137726/limits-of-ios-6-nda

Comment: @Douglas- The reason why I asked here was I thought may be somebody would have worked on it or faced the same problem(what if it is still in beta). That's all. 

Thanks for the response.

Comment: That’s fine. I have had some small issues with iOS 6, but in different areas (regarding setting background images on UITableView).

Comment: So, how did you fix these unexpected issues?

Comment: In my case, I discovered my old way wasn’t documented to work anyway.
(fixed by using `self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;` instead of `self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];`) – probably doesn’t apply to your layout problems.

Comment: Probably, you're adding root view controller's view as a subview to the **keyWindow**. In this case try to set root view controller to the **keyWindow**.

Comment: try why artem says: instead of window addsubview;vc.view do window setrootviewcontroller:vc

Answer (score 1):

```
self.tableView.backgroundView = nil; 
tableView.alpha = 1.0;
```

worked perfectly for me.